# Flash Debugger in IDEA

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, flash, intellij-idea

When I try to use Flash Player debugger in IDEA I get such message

> Waiting for Player to connect
>   Failed to connect; session timed out.
>   Ensure that:
>    1. you compiled your Flash movie with debugging on, and
>    2. you are running the Debugger version of the Flash Player.

Although I managed path to the debugger in Remote Configuration. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.
Right click on Flash Player -> Debug -> localhost option is enabled.

The problem was I had specified a certain port. But IDEA uses its own default port only so you don't need to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Remote debug** then you need to ensure that your browser has Flash Player Debugger installed and enabled.

Comment: Thanks. But I debug in standalone debuger and not in browser.

Comment: Thanks! Good luck